# Mostrar los mensajes de error en rojo, está desplegando todo el código html del mensaje en vez del error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

Quiero desplegar los mensajes de error en color rojo mediante el texto que va dentro de ErrorMessage = "......." pero no despliega dicho error, lo que está desplegando es todo el código que se definió en cada una de las validaciones.

**Observación: Funciona en Chrome más no en Mozilla.**

namespace Sistem_Ventas.Areas.Usuarios.Models
{
    public class InputModelRegistrar
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo nombre es obligatorio ")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo apellido es obligatorio </font>")]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo NID es obligatorio </font>")]
    public string NID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo ´teléfono es obligatorio </font>")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo correo electrónico es obligatorio </font>")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El correo electrónico no tiene un formato válido </font>")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo contraseña es obligatorio </font>")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El número de carácteres de {0} debe ser al menos {1}  carácteres</font>", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

}

[image: Código del mensaje de error que se desea desplegar]

[image: Despliega el código no el mensaje de error en rojo]

Comment: Probaste con ErrorColor? Sino en tu css  `.input-validation-error {
        background-color: #FF0000;`
    }

Comment: @Fran Islas, acabo de darme cuenta que el código sin modificarlo funciona en Chrome, pero despliega todo el mensaje con las propiedades si lo hago con Mozilla. Alguna solución?

Comment: @Fran Islas, creo la clase .input-validation-error en mi css y como se usa?.